# How to use immutable objects to replace observer pattern

Tags: javascript, immutability, observer-pattern

I was happy [when O.o was announced](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/es7/observe/) but turns out it's [not in the woodwork anymore](https://esdiscuss.org/topic/an-update-on-object-observe). One of the advised [replacement libraries](https://github.com/MaxArt2501/object-observe) explains it on its github page as such:

> Web development evolved in the direction of functional programming and immutable objects, so that's where we all should look at.

Although I've been hearing about immutable data structures recently I still don't know how I'm supposed to use them to replace the functionality of the observer pattern.

Comment: Please watch this video: React.js Conf 2015 - Immutable Data and React.

Comment: You forgot the hyperlink in your comment

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=I7IdS-PbEgI&feature=youtu.be&t=16m56s sorry...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you misunderstood the message of that.

Immutable data and observers (reactive programming) are a great pairing. It's just that `Object.observe` in particular becomes redundant - if `Object` doesn't change, what exactly are you trying to `observe` here?

The library you linked to is a compatibility patch for browsers that don't (yet) support the ECMA standard for `Object.observe`. Since the standard retracted the interface, this is no longer valid. That doesn't mean someone can't keep this as a library - it just means it's no longer a compatibility patch. That's all that's meant by the comment, IMO.

[Change and its detection in Javascript frameworks](http://teropa.info/blog/2015/03/02/change-and-its-detection-in-javascript-frameworks.html) is a pretty good read on the topic. The last point, Om, basically talks about a reactive approach over immutable data, with plenty of links for deeper study. Of course, I still recommend reading the whole article - it nicely outlines how the state change approach changed over the years, and as such, gives you the details you want - what were the problems with our old approaches that are solved by the new (50 year old :P) paradigm. Note that only the state itself is immutable - you can switch states just fine and that's the thing you're observing.

Answer (score 1):

Immutable data structures do not exactly replace the functionality of the observer pattern, they merely make it redundant. Immutability simply means "unable to change", so whereas the observer pattern tells you when objects change, using immutable objects means that they will never be able to change (if you do need to add or remove values, then you would create a new immutable object), so you don't need to worry about handling change events any more. You can use [Immutable.js](https://github.com/facebook/immutable-js) to get immutable Maps or Lists or Stacks or other complex data structures (and you may want to read *The case for Immutability* on that page). Or you can use plain javascript (the Object.freeze function introduced in ES5.1) to make object literals immutable:

```
var o = { a: 99 };
Object.freeze(o); // make o immutable
o.a = 100; // a still equals 99, this assignment silently fails because o is immutable
```

Comment: You're not explaining why immutables make observer redundants. My data will still change and those changes need to be handled somehow.